# Adding a PowerBI report as a static tab app on Microsoft Teams with SSO enabled

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, microsoft-teams

Im stumped. I keep finding different sources and it doesn't help that there are like 6 different methods for creating MS Teams apps. The title pretty much says it all. I have a PowerBI report that I want to turn into a MS Teams app so it is easily accessible for everyone. Now I was able to make this app with App Studio in teams and it works on the Browser Version of MS Teams but not the Desktop version because it prompts users for login on the Desktop Version. Now I tried giving app studio a newly made app id I made in azure for the AAD App ID Field.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @dpasten- Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end?

Comment: Please have look into this doc-https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/announcing-new-power-bi-tab-for-microsoft-teams/

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I appreciate your reply! So that doc you sent is exactly what we want visually and functionally. However, we would want that as a static (personal) tab rather than as a channel/shared tab if that makes sense? I have tried creating an app using the template on vs code (hello world with SSO) but have had no luck so far. Thanks again on the reply!

Comment: Related thread-https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/building-a-custom-app-that-install-a-powerbi-tab-with-report/m-p/1823479
hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is trying to replicate this behaviour I was able to do it!
You have to create a teams app and create a public tab linking to your powerBI page in a SharePoint site. This is how I did it and it is good enough. If anyone can come up with a better answer that has an SSO callback in the URL for the powerBI embedded link please do let us know how!